# Asterisk in Java Play MVC Framework's Routes File

Tags: java, playframework, routes

I've inherited a project in the Play Framework.  I'm in the process of modifying the conf/routes file and was wondering why asterisks were used instead of the normal HTTP methods as described in the documentation here:
http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/JavaRouting

Here's and example of what I mean:

```
# Top level pages
GET     /how-tradjenta-works                    Application.about
GET     /prescription-savings-card              SavingsCard.index
*       /prescription-savings-card/qualify      SavingsCard.qualify
```

As you can see, the third route definition has that asterisk.  What gives?

Comment: Are you sure this is version 2.X? Looks like 1.X to me.

Comment: Yeah,that was it. The source I'm working with is 1.x and i was looking at the 2.x documentations.  Oops!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its the request type to serve for the route, GET, POST, or either/both (*). It lets you specify a different route for the same url based on the request type. For example you could set a different controller action on post for the same URI.

Comment: Sooooo you're saying the asterisk is used as a wildcard as it often is in things like regex?   ;-)

Comment: Marked you correct since you were first to answer.  Essentially giving the same data.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at an older version of the doc:

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.0/routes

you'll see it says:

> If you specify * as method, this route will match the HTTP Request for
>   any methods.

Comment: Thanks for linking to the old doc.  Strange they wouldn't carry it over to the latest.

Comment: @SBerg413 This is not a matter of "carrying old documentation". The thing is that Play has changed substantially from version 1 to 2.

Comment: @Carsten Thanks for the heads up.  I'm going to continue to re-use and  iteration of v1.X.  Just out of curiosity, is the asterisk wildcard something they deprecated or removed entirely in v2.X?